# Validating Json file with Avro Schema

Tags: json, go, avro

I'm trying to check if a Json string matches an Avro schema. I don't care about doing serialization of the data, just getting a bool result of `isValidJson=true/false`.
I'll go with every **golang** library.
I've tried to write something with this [goavro](https://github.com/linkedin/goavro) lib, but it didn't work for me, maybe because I'm new to golang.

Desired pseudo code:

```
func main() {
    avroSchema := 
    `{"type":"record","name":"raw","namespace":"events","fields":[{"name":"my_int","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"my_string","type":["null","string"],"default":"null"},{"name":"my_string2","type":null}]}`
    jsonString := `{"my_int": 3, "my_string": "foo", "my_string2": null}`
    ok ;= isValidJson(jsonString, avroSchema)
}
```

Any idea how to implement the `isValidJson(..)` method?

Comment: What's not working? Other than the fact that this does not even compile?

Comment: @marc Yes I know, I'm new to golang. I'm trying to validate that the Json string is valid according to the provided schema. Any idea how to do that or which lib to use with go and how? It's very easy via Java and Python, but I couldn't find a way to do this validation in golang. I'll fix the method to represent a psudo code that I want to implement.

Comment: There nothing in the [docs]((https://godoc.org/github.com/linkedin/goavro) about validating, it either parses or it does not. Use [codec.NativeFromTextual](https://godoc.org/github.com/linkedin/goavro#Codec.NativeFromTextual) to parse a json string.

Comment: @marc I tried that method and couldn't work with it. If the jsonString parses or return err upon failure it's excellent. This means that `err == nil` is a successful parsing. Does it work for you based on my inputs.

Comment: Your schema is invalid json, so you can't even build a codec.

Comment: @marc I tried this too:
`jsonString := "{\"my_int\": 3, \"my_string2\": \"foo\"}"`
If something is broken on my end, I'll appreciate a code snippet that changes my inputs. BTW, I can't used struct since I have 80 unique fields and they are changing frequently. Many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Your schema json is invalid, it's missing the terminating `}`, so `goavro.NewCodec` returns an error.

Then your json string definitely doesn't match the schema, the json values must be a `{type: value}`.

You can use the following corrected schema and example string to validate it.

```
func main() {
  avroSchema := `
{ 
   "type":"record",
   "name":"raw",
   "namespace":"events",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"my_int",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "int"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"my_string",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "string"
         ],
         "default":null
      },
      {
         "name":"my_string2",
         "type":"null"
      }
   ]
}`
  codec, err := goavro.NewCodec(avroSchema)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Codec error: %v", err)
  }

  jsonString := `{"my_int": {"int":3}, "my_string": {"string":"foo"}, "my_string2": null}`

  decoded, _, err := codec.NativeFromTextual([]byte(jsonString))
  if err != nil { 
    log.Fatalf("NativeFromTextual error: %v", err)
  } 
  log.Println("Decoded:", decoded)
}
```

This prints:

> Decoded: map[my_int:map[int:3] my_string:map[string:foo]
>   my_string2:]

Comment: you are the puppet master!
Is there a way to pass a regular Json string like the one I've mentioned in my question or to use a built-in converter that does that for me?

Comment: No idea, you'll have to search around.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll write my own parser and if it's good enough I'll share it here.